# juju MAAS machines dns-name ip address

Tags: dns, juju, maas

Is there a way to pick a DNS A record for machines added using juju machine or annotations that can be used in bundle?
For example, I need "dns-name: 10.146.x.x" instead of "dnsname: 10.127.0.1".

```
model: test
machines:
  "0":
    juju-status:
      current: started
      since: 18 Dec 2018 13:08:21-08:00
      version: 2.4.7
    dns-name: 10.127.0.1
    ip-addresses:
    - 10.127.0.1
    - 10.146.x.x
    instance-id: 73mrn7
    machine-status:
      current: running
      message: Deployed
      since: 18 Dec 2018 13:07:41-08:00
    series: bionic
    network-interfaces:
      eno1:
        ip-addresses:
        - 10.146.x.x
        mac-address: 7c:d3:0a:x:x:x:
        gateway: 10.146.x.x
        dns-nameservers:
        - 172.27.x.x
        space: primary
        is-up: true
      eno4:
        ip-addresses:
        - 10.127.0.1
        mac-address: 7c:d3:0a:x:x:x
        space: tunspace
        is-up: true
    hardware: arch=amd64 cores=40 mem=98304M tags=compute,int-bind availability-zone=default
```